How to solve the problem Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not determine wrapper version.
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.wrapperVersion(GradleWrapperMain.java:111)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No build receipt resource found.
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.wrapperVersion(GradleWrapperMain.java:97)
... 1 more
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
fix found a solution to this problem

Hey, which IDE are you using ?

hey, I'm using visual studio code

If so:

Find Android folder from your side bar
tap right click of your mouse
find open in Android Studio and click it
After opening AS, it will download all needed gradles itself(Wait until the download is complete!)
After completed downloading you can try one more time in your VS code


the same error still occurs. helpp me

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
